# 1920s postcard joke meaning? Cut some ice

Tags: etymology, american-english, phrase-meaning, jokes, vernacular

Can anyone explain the meaning of this 1920’s postcard?
The text reads:
“I should worry like the iceman and cut some ice.”
Next to this is a cartoon of a little boy with an axe chopping a large block of ice. I am attaching an image here.

I’m assuming it’s a joke… a visual pun or some other word play. It could be playing off of the phrase “doesn’t cut ice with me”… meaning the argument or person in question has no influence or effect on the speaker… but even if that’s true I still have no idea what it means..

See this thread for a discussion about the origin of that phrase “cut ice with me”:
[Is Iroquoi the origin of the American idiom “cuts no ice with me”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/586774/is-iroquoi-the-origin-of-the-american-idiom-cuts-no-ice-with-me)

Anyone have thoughts?

Note: the stamp is postmarked 1920… I don’t actually know when the postcard was printed. [image: I should worry like the iceman and cut some ice]

Comment: Just a note: the iceman may be the man who delivered the ice to (non-poor) people's kitchens before the age of the refrigerator. Ice from Canada used to be brought to Europe on very large ships all the time just for people's ice-boxes at home.

Comment: Yes agreed, iceman would seem to mean the person who delivered blocks of ice. The cartoon block of ice would seem to support that interpretation… but here there could be a double meaning… perhaps iceman meaning someone with “nerves of steel” ie not easily worried… which connects to the “I should worry” part… meaning “I’m not worried”… seems to me the card is stringing together three common phrases/slang terms: 1. “I should worry”; 2. “Iceman”; 3. “Cut ice”… but still I feel I don’t exactly get the joke.

Comment: This "I should worry..." thing seems to have been a 1900's postcard-formula. Search google for `I should worry postcards` to see a lot more equally inscrutable reults. Also see [this](https://www.ebay.com/itm/235087774371).

Comment: We can at least say that *I should worry* is sarcastic - I ain't worried because ...

Comment: @Heartspring 1900s meme template?

Comment: Consider also the idiom s.t. "[cuts no ice](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cut%20no%20ice)" with s.o.

Comment: @BrianDonovan: Which would make the antonym "cut some ice" mean to be important to someone.

Comment: Perhaps related: lyrics in _Do I Worry_ by The Ink Spots include 'Do I worry when the iceman calls?' [[mojim](https://mojim.com/usy123960x1x34.htm)] //// Perhaps the joke anticipates global warming and the loss of the resource to the iceman. _Make ice while the sun shines._

Answer (score 2):

Having seen another "I should worry" postcard (https://www.ebay.com/itm/235087774371), I suppose an iceman is always worried because his merchandise melts easily. To "worry like the iceman" would mean that someone must act with no delay. A corruption of "I should hurry like the iceman", perhaps?

Comment: Especially given that the ice came from ice lakes 100's of miles away, by train, to places like NYC in the summer, tons in carriages every day. For paris i know it came from the Alps the lake was in shadow and had dedicated train tracks.